# Django can't delete user from my database

Tags: python, django, database, sql-delete

I have a problem with my Django project. I need to delete 1 or more users from my database but I can't do it because it returns this error:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

I tried deleting it from my views but it didn't work. Than I went and used admin panel to try to delete it but the same problem happened.

If someone could give some advice or suggestion that would be great.
 Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], including the complete error traceback.  FWIW it looks like your `User` model's `__str__`  method returns a tuple instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. I was returning tuple in my models `__str__` function instead of a string which worked while users existed but it for some reason didn't when I tried to delete or as I later found out create a new user.